Xero webhook in Xero API - Response should be 401, fails even when 401 sent
I suspect this is something really dumb, but here's the situation and the code, if anyone can spot it. I've been at it for some time now.
Im attempting to set up my app to use a Xero webhook following along the docs here
Here is a reduced version of what I'm trying to do:
function xero_payment_detected(){

    $xero_wh_key = $_ENV['my_key'];

    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $payload_hash = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $xero_wh_key, true));
    
    $headers = getallheaders();
    $xero_validation_header = $headers['X-Xero-Signature'];
    
    $is_valid_payload = ($payload_hash === $xero_validation_header);
    
    if( $is_valid_payload ){
        
        http_response_code(200);
        logging_function("test 1");
      
    } else {
        
        http_response_code(401);
        logging_function("test 2");                       
       
    } // end if else
         
            
}// end fn

I've got some logging in both the 'if' and the 'else' and can see that when I trigger the webhook to run, Xero sends back an intentional good request and an intentional bad one (as described here) to verify it's set up correctly.
Both set of logging run correctly, so I can see that the if/else itself is not at fault. The issue is this: Even though Im responding with a 401 when the payload isnt valid, I continually receive "Response to incorrectly signed payload not 401" on Xero's side of things. It seems like Xero's server is not accepting the required 401 I'm putting down.
For additional context, this site is a https site with a response well within Xero's required bounds of 5s (it's something like 0.0001).
Am I missing something?
Solved
http_response_code(401) was not setting the response code
Explicitly setting header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized") fixes it.
As to why, check out the comments under: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php
(specifically under the phrase 'Do not mix the use of http_response_code() and manually setting  the response code header')
Thanks to all who commented!

Are you sure this is the function being called at all? $_ENV('my_key') doesn't seem like valid PHP code, as you're trying to use a superglobal as a function?

What happens, when you send these requests yourself, either from a different server, or via a testing tool like postman - do you get the expected 401 response then?

@MatsLindh ah well spotted, I just mistyped the example

@C3roe Ah didn't think of that, cheers! So it was coming back with a 200, and this is now corrected now that I've set header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
Not sure I fully understand why though, I thought that  http_response_code(401); would have the same effect

Answer taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php (courtesy of viaujoc at videotron dot ca)

"Do not mix the use of http_response_code() and manually setting  the
response code header because the actual HTTP status code being
returned by the web server may not end up as expected.
http_response_code() does not work if the response code has previously
been set using the header() function.
The raw HTTP response will be (notice the actual status code on the
first line does not match the printed http_response_code in the body):
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 13:49:08 GMT Server:
Apache Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
403
I only tested it on Apache. I am not sure if this behavior is specific
to Apache or common to all PHP distributions."

